# Ionic 4. How refresh or update page in super-tab

Tags: ionic4, supertab

I have a "ParentPage" page with supertabs:

```
  <super-tabs-toolbar slot="top">
    <super-tab-button>
      <ion-label>ChildPage 1</ion-label>
    </super-tab-button>
    <super-tab-button>
      <ion-label>ChildPage 2</ion-label>
    </super-tab-button>

  </super-tabs-toolbar>

  <super-tabs-container>

    <super-tab>
      <ion-nav [root]="childPage1"></ion-nav>
    </super-tab>
    <super-tab>
      <ion-nav [root]="childPage2"></ion-nav>
    </super-tab>

  </super-tabs-container>

 </super-tabs>
```

From the "ParentPage" page I modify the data of "childPage1", but "childPage1" is not updated visually, and the data is updated.

Comment: It depends the data is being updated on device storage or webapi ?

Comment: in webapi, I print the data in a console.log, but visually it is not updated (it is a list of items)

Comment: Edit your answer and put the ts page and html page and anything that isbrealated to what you want to have, since here you put the html layout of supertabs which means nothing to the introduction you gave.